# Get all Comments made by Me from fb:comments sites

Tags: comments, facebook-fql

I'm looking for a way to get all comments made by me.

Right now I can get comments to my Wall and other people's walls. What I'm looking for is any Comments made by me on any fb:comments site.

The ideal would be to create a FQL query on the comments table with a "WHERE fromid = me()".

```
SELECT fromid, text, username, text, comments FROM comment WHERE fromid = me();
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

This doesn't work however because the fromid field is not indexable.

The 2nd example in the link above gives me a way to do this if I have the URL of the page I'm posting on.

But I want on ANY page I've posted on.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: So did you find out ?

Comment: the short answer is that you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:
The comments for every URL can be accessed via the graph API. Simply go to: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=%YOUR_URL%

Hope it helps,
Luca

Comment: Thanks Luca, unless I'm missing something this doesn't do what I need. This works for a known URL blog. So lets say I have a blog using fb:comments (xx.com), or I want to get comments from a particular URL, like techcrunch.com.